# .NET Standard: Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider does not ask for credentials

Tags: wcf, authentication, .net-standard

In a c# console application, whenever I clicked Add > Service Reference and inserted a WCF URI, and I would be prompted to type my credentials:

[image]

When I try to do the same thing now in a **.NET Standard** solution (and after upgrading my Visual Studio to v15.5.6), I click Add > Connected Service > Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider, I input the URI but I do not get the prompt for credentials, I simply get error 502 Bad Gateway!

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the Connected Service to ask for my credentials?

PS: I tried adding the username/password in plain text in the URI (using **username:password@** syntax) but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative can you not use the browse button to point to the .wsdl file in the Local disk. 
That way you are guaranteed your reference is pointing to the correct path.

Comment: Hey @jayce, I already tried downloading the wsdl xml file on the Local disk and browse for it in the service call, but I could not proceed without the xsd... Also the question still remains, why don't I get prompted for credentials in the .NET Standard solution's WCF Web Service Reference Provider, like in the 1st screenshot?

Comment: Have you explored the Identity tags in -                                       <endpoint address="http://some_service"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Iblabla"
          contract="FullyQualifiedNamespaceAndContractName" name="WSHttpBinding_blabla">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="username@domain.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>

Comment: From what I can tell there's no app.config in .NET Standard... Do you know where the binding configurations could be stored instead?